# What would be some consequences if >80% of people were women?

Tags: gender, family, eugenics

**The world**: a dictatorship with advanced biology. The state controls reproduction for eugenic purposes, and engineers society for harmony. (The same could be said of *Brave New World*. There are differences, but *Brave New World* gives you a close-enough first idea.)

**The question**: would the state choose to make most embryos female? This can easily be done via [sperm sexing](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41596-020-0348-y). There are at least two obvious benefits from making only 1 in 5 people male: lower crime (because men are more crime-prone than women; lots of stats on this), and less [sexual conflict](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sexual_conflict) (because the supply:demand ratio in the dating marketplace would be rebalanced). Remember the state policies are directed at social harmony above all else. ***BUT WHAT ARE THE CONS, ESPECIALLY UNFORESEEN ONES???***

While some jobs (construction, military, sports) require physical strength, I don't see this as an issue, as you don't need 50% of your population to do these jobs, and there are still *some* men. The technology is industrialised, 21st century, so there's not massive amounts of manual labour.

In more extreme scenarios, I was thinking they might make only 1 in 40 male.

The obvious thing to think about is the effects on the family unit...

Comment: Whether the state engages a... "womenization" plan? is not the same as what consequences there would be. You should focus on the latter as it will help you with the first and is more accepted, but you also need to pick a specific area (workplace, politics, science...) and tell us the culture in more details. "What if" questions are generally too broad if unconstrained.

Comment: Policies get set for reasons. So they'll go/don't go on the plan depending on the anticipated consequences.

Comment: Why would thier be less sexual conflict?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it fails "the book test": If you can imagine an entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much.

Comment: @wokopa But this site is not here to deal with what would a character -individual or organization- would choose (off-topic for being [storybuilding](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3300/80336)). We can imagine the likely consequences, but why a dictator choose this political course is not solely dependent on the society. They may be very well half insane and this would be a perfectly valid reason. You really should do what I'm suggesting you (if not more) if you want to have a chance to avoid closure (or to reopen it later, we're already at 4/5 votes to close).

Comment: Your military would have problems. Humanity is competitive by evolutionary nature. The statistics may say there is more male crime than female, but after 10 years experience in retail, it's a whole lot closer to 50/50. Sex, race, age... Statistics only reflect reported crime, not actual crime, and then usually only serious crime, not shoplifting (etc.). I think you need more research into the viability of what you're trying to pitch.

Comment: It's also good to explicate *how* something is like Brave New World. Not everyone has read the book or knows it by heart.

Comment: What is the tech level of this world? Biology is advanced, Ok, but what about construction and military?

Comment: @JBH retail experience is misleading: shoplifting is the only area of crime that is about 50:50

Comment: @wokopa You have an argument, but more and more women are found guilty of white collar crime, so that's out. More and more women are guilty of bullying and aggression, so that eliminates most physical altercation crimes. And women are more and more frequently found guilty of both drug use and drug dealing. And most police (according to the two policemen I know) are far more willing to let women off with a warning than men, and likewise judges tend to be more lenient. That basically leaves very violent crime, like murder. I trust my experience more than I trust statistics.

Answer (score 2):

1.More sexual competition: While men have no reason to compete sexually but the sex competition between woman would be  Fierce.

2. Sexual dissatisfaction:  One man alone cannot support the entire sexual needs of 40 woman.  Chances are hes gonna be see most of these women once a month if then. Making most women sexually Dissatisfied.
3. Emotional dissatisfaction, Sex isn't entirely just about sex. More often than not people also want emotional bonding and relational connection.  If sex was all we wanted Then we wouldn't form relationships. It's highly unlikely that your male has the time and energy to maintain a close personal emotional relationship with 40 women at once.
4. Is in short the woman of your world would be Sex deprived, lonely,  And in constant competition with each other.

5.competition between children,  Something else to consider is this effect on sibling rivalry. Typically in most Polygamous societies Children of different wives often see themselves in competition with each other even more than is regular siblings. The reasons are pretty obvious When you have 40 wives You have to Spread your love and attention not just between 40 kids but 40 households. Something your male probably is just going to be unable to do.  Inevitably making his love and attention a limited resource that his children from different households will compete to obtain,  Not exactly a healthy emotional environment to raise kids.  Especially if you add to the already existing rivalries between his wives Competing to satisfy their sexual and emotional needs.

Comment: The OP specified 1-4, not 1-40, as the default case.

Comment: His statement at the end seems to indicate that his is considering 1 to 40.

Comment: The history of infighting in the harem is horrific.  And once you have admitted polygamy, there is no reason why a man could not accumulate 40 even if the ratio is 1 to 4 -- thus reintroducing the unattached male with all his problems.